# Select information about reference constraints

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to solve the following problem (with Oracle 11g database): I need to get all table columns using `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` table and information about reference constraints (name of table and column referenced by this column), for example:

```
 No. Column        Details 
 --- -----------   ------------------------------------------------------
   1 foo_id        Type   : NUMBER(9)
                   Constr : "foo_fk" References foo_table(id)

   2 bar_id        Type   : NUMBER(9)
                   Constr : "bar_fk"  References bar_table(id)

   2 date_created  Type   : Date
```

Information about table's constraints stores in `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`, detailed description of constraint (table and column name) stores in `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`.
For now I've got this code:

```
SELECT
  ROWNUM as "No.",
  t.COLUMN_NAME as "Имя столбца",
  'Type:   ' || t.DATA_TYPE || (SELECT CASE
          WHEN ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
            THEN chr(10) || 'Constr: ' || allcc.CONSTRAINT_NAME ||
            ' References ' || (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) ||
            '(' || (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) || ')'
          ELSE ''
          END AS Contype FROM DUAL) As "Атрибуты",
  ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE

FROM
  ALL_CONS_COLUMNS allcc

INNER JOIN
  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
  ON t.TABLE_NAME = allcc.TABLE_NAME
  AND t.COLUMN_NAME = allcc.COLUMN_NAME

INNER JOIN
  (SELECT (CASE WHEN CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN 'R' ELSE NULL END) as CONSTRAINT_TYPE, CONSTRAINT_NAME, R_CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS) ac
  ON ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME = allcc.CONSTRAINT_NAME

WHERE
  t.TABLE_NAME = 'SUPPLIES';
```

But if column has more than 1 constraint, it will be duplicated in output for each constraint:

```
No. Column              Details:
1   ID_SUPPLIER         Type: NUMBER    
2   ID_SHOP             Type: NUMBER    
3   DATE_SUPPLY         Type: DATE  
4   ID                  Type: NUMBER    
5   ID_SHOP             Type: NUMBER
                        Constr: FK_SUPPLIES_SHOP References SHOPS(ID)
6   ID_SUPPLIER         Type: NUMBER
                        Constr: FK_SUPPLIES_SUPPLIER References SUPPLIERS(ID)
```

In this example ID_SUPPLIER duplicates twice for 2 constraints (reference and not null).
Is it possible to avoid duplicates and solve this problem without using PL\SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use windowing functions to get rid of the duplicate rows; here, I use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select rownum as no,
       v1.*
  from (SELECT t.COLUMN_NAME,
               'Type:   ' || t.DATA_TYPE ||
               (SELECT CASE
                         WHEN ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN
                          chr(10) || 'Constr: ' || allcc.CONSTRAINT_NAME || ' References ' ||
                          (SELECT TABLE_NAME
                             FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
                            WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) || '(' ||
                          (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                             FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
                            WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME) || ')'
                         ELSE
                          ''
                       END AS Contype
                  FROM DUAL) As description,
               ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
               row_number() over(partition by allcc.column_name order by(case constraint_type
                 when 'R' then
                  1
                 else
                  2
               end)) as rn
          FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS allcc
         INNER JOIN ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
            ON t.TABLE_NAME = allcc.TABLE_NAME
           AND t.COLUMN_NAME = allcc.COLUMN_NAME
         INNER JOIN (SELECT (CASE
                             WHEN CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN
                              'R'
                             ELSE
                              NULL
                           END) as CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                           CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                           R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
                      FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS) ac
            ON ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME = allcc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
         WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'SUPPLIES') v1
 where rn = 1;
```

This

- assigns rn = 1 to each referential constraint
- assigns rn = 1 to other constraint types if no referential constraint is present for the same column (unless there's another non-referential constraint on the column; in that case, only one of them gets rn = 1)
- assigns rn > 1 other constraint types if a referential constraint is present
- removes all rows whose rn > 1